# python command line argument parsing

Tags: python, python-3.x, arguments, parameter-passing

If my shell variable is like the following ( key value separated by spaces ). Example below:

`$ var="key1=value1 key2=value2"`

`$ python3 create_user.py abc ${var}`

```
['create_user.py', 'abc', 'key1=value1', 'key2=value2']
```

It is treating each key-value as a separate argument.

But,  i am looking for is the following outcome from variable.

`['create_user.py', 'abc', 'key1=value1 key2=value2']`

Essentially, i want the second argument $var to be treated as a string in single quote.

Comment: `python3 create_user.py abc "$var"`.

Comment: ```$ python3 create_user.py abc "${var}"
['create_user.py', 'abc', 'key1=value1 key2=value2']```

Answer (score 1):

```
#if you do not change shell script
import sys
second_arg = sys.argv[2]+' '+sys.argv[3]
#or, change shell script accordingly (did not test it..)
$ var="'key1=value1 key2=value2'"
$ python3 create_user.py abc ${var}
#than
import sys
second_arg = sys.argv[2]
```